# How can I make TinyMCE content responsive in Angular innerHtml?

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE to make some content for a page with Angular, this is the problem, i need to make it responsive i mean in desktop mode it is awesome, but on mobile, the content doesn't work, the content is stored in MySQL so i get it form a service, like this:

```
this.courseService.getCourse().subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(data)
  this.curso = data
})
```

The html is is data.content and is like this = `<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-width: 0px;\" border=\"1\"><colgroup><col style=\"width: 50%;\">....`
so I printed out this way: `<div [innerHTML]="sanitizedHtmlContent"></div>` where sanitizedcontent is this:

```
get sanitizedHtmlContent(): SafeHtml {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.course?.content);
}
```

I try to read the html content and in some tags in add some inline styles, and some of it work, but it makes a los of mistakes, I do it like this:

```
addInline(html: string, tagName: string, styles: string): string {
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = html;

const elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].setAttribute('style', styles);
}

return element.innerHTML;
```

}

and i remove them this way:

```
delInline(html: string, tagName: string, styles: string): string {
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = html;

const elements = elemento.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const styleAttr = elements[i].getAttribute('style');
  if (styleAttr && styleAttr.indexOf(styles) !== -1) {
    elements[i].setAttribute('style', styleAttr.replace(styles, ''));
  }
}
return element.innerHTML;
}
```

this are activated when the width change and when the component starts: this works but not with all tags some of them crash and might not display some things. I don't know if this can be done in the editor.